# hide a portion of button under textedit

Tags: android

I am trying to achieve exactly something like this

[image]
 - a text view on left and a button to its right
 - Button should be wrap_text
 - textedit should occupy the remaining space

If you carefully see the image in the image the buttons left curved border are hiding under the text view.

I am using relative layout to adjust the button height according to this

[How to get a button's height to match another element's height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188859/how-to-get-a-buttons-height-to-match-another-elements-height)

But I am unable to hide the left portion of the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the `Button` isn't hidden under the `EditText`.

They used custom background for that button, which is 9 patch png image. You can achieve this by providing your 9 patch images for both `EditText` and `Button` with 0 margin between them.

[Here](http://tekeye.biz/2012/android-9patch-files) is a nice tutorial about using 9 patch png.

Another post to consider is [Buttons with (niceley) stretched background.](http://www.anddev.org/tutorial_buttons_with_niceley_stretched_background-t4369.html)

Comment: I know I can use 9 patch image . But I have my other buttons of the same background which are full ( not hidden) . So just for one button creating another 9patch image is overwork . simple solution would be to slide the button below the `edittext`

Answer (score 0):

add android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp" to the button

Comment: as if it was so simple ?? try it out.. it doesn't slide below with even -100 dp