# match_parent inside wrap_content doesn't work on api 18

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, parent-child, android-relativelayout

I have a RelativeLayout that doesn't take up the whole screen and holds two child views. Both children are LinearLayouts, and the height of the 2nd child is dependent on the 1st child.

I followed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16674917/5538168), which I modified to produce the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/parentWrapper"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#232323"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
    <!-- 1st child -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/childTWrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/iconWrapper"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lastTime"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lastAuthor"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- 2nd child; matches height of first child -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/iconWrapper"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/childTWrapper"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingRight="18dp">
        <!-- images -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/hide"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:paddingLeft="12dp"
            android:paddingRight="12dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_hide"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:paddingLeft="12dp"
            android:paddingRight="12dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_profile"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/browser"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:paddingLeft="12dp"
            android:paddingRight="12dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_browser"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now, the problem is that I want the 2nd LinearLayout's children (ImageViews) to match the height of their parent. This leads to a `match_parent` view being nested inside a `wrap_content` view. Even if I change the LinearLayout's height to `match_parent`, it is still ultimately inside a RelativeLayout with height `wrap_content`.

On APIs > 18, this works fine:
[image]

On APIs <= 18, however, the following result is produced:
[image]

Any idea on how to fix this to support older API versions?

Comment: Because "match_parent inside wrap_content" doesn't make sens at all. (you have circular references)

Comment: @Selvin Yes, but how else would you fill a non-fullscreen view's height?

Answer (score 0):

set your both layout **height to match_parent and width to wrap_content** and set **android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"** and **android:gravity="center_vertical"**.

Comment: If you set the first LinearLayout's height to match_parent, the element takes up the entire screen, which I do not want. The parent's layout height is set to wrap_content.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this out, but I noticed a few things that may cause issues.. Try out these changes and see how it works.  I've added some comments attempting to explain my changes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Relative layout doesn't use the orientation attribute so I nixed that -->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/parentWrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#232323">
    <!-- 1st child -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/childTWrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/iconWrapper"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lastTime"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lastAuthor"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- 2nd child; matches height of first child -->
    <!-- Set the top AND bottom of this linear layout to be aligned with the first child, rather than aligning it to the top of the parent.  You also probably don't want the centerVertical attribute because that centers the LinearLayout and not it's children. --> 
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/iconWrapper"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/childTWrapper"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/childTWrapper"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingRight="18dp">
        <!-- images -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/hide"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:paddingLeft="12dp"
            android:paddingRight="12dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_hide"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:paddingLeft="12dp"
            android:paddingRight="12dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_profile"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/browser"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:paddingLeft="12dp"
            android:paddingRight="12dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_browser"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

If that doesn't work, or if you want to remove the unnecessary second LinearLayout, you could align each of the ImageView elements with the first child... That would look like this:

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lastTime"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lastAuthor"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- images -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/hide"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/childTWrapper"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/childTWrapper"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/childTWrapper"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:paddingRight="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_hide"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/childTWrapper"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/childTWrapper"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/hide"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:paddingRight="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_profile"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/browser"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/childTWrapper"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/childTWrapper"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/profile"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:paddingRight="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_browser"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

You could also go even a level further and remove the *other* LinearLayout but I'll leave that as an exercise for whoever wants to try :-)